# How to set time interval api call in ios objective c and reload the table view after getting success

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to ios development .I have issue . I need to call api after set time interval (ios objective c) . After getting success it should load the table view .

Comment: show ur tried code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is what I would do...

**Step 1 :** *Call webservice `[self makeWebserviceCall]`*

**Step 2 :** *When webservice call is done, use `NSTimer` in `- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {`*

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(makeWebserviceCall) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
                                        ^^^ --> change this to increase more
```

That's it...

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code :

```
// Delay execution of my block for 10 seconds.
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 10 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     // Call API
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NSTimer` class for this

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:YOUR_TIME_INTERVAL target:self selector:@selector(apiCall:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

or use

```
[self performSelector:@selector(apiCall:) withObject:nil afterDelay:YOUR_TIME_INTERVAL];
```

and in `apiCall` method

```
[self performSelector:_cmd withObject:nil afterDelay:YOUR_TIME_INTERVAL];
```

But I think this way less clear

Answer (score 1):

```
#define kAutoInterval 5.00f

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:kAutoInterval target:self selector:@selector(startUpdatingValues) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

Comment: you should use repeats: NO and in startUpdatingValues [timer invalidate]; timer = nil;